# if statement in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am getting the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'.
```

on this line:

```
  use SalesDWH
go
if (select isnumeric(result))=1
begin
select  max(cast(result) as decimal(10,2)) from testresults 

end
```

testresults table contains about 21 million rows of data.

what am i doing wrong? thanks so much.

thank you everyone for you rhelp.

i've changed the code to:

```
 use SalesDWH
    go
    if (select isnumeric(result))=1
    begin
    select  max(cast(result as decimal(10,2))) from testresults

    end
```

and now i am getting error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'result'.
```

it's definitely a valid column

i took kris' suggestion and did this:

```
 use SalesDWH
    go
    SELECT MAX( CAST( [Result] AS DECIMAL(9,2) ) )
FROM [testresults]
WHERE ISNUMERIC( [Result] ) = 1

    and dbo.isReallyNumeric([Result]) = 1 
    and dbo.isReallyInteger([Result]) = 1
```

the functions are here http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html

and the result that i got was `NULL`!!!!!

i need a numeric result. what am i doing wrong?

here is a sample of the data:

```
625857  AMPH-AMPHETAMINES   357.1   EBB74CF9-D12D-4FBC-917F-91D9DAC169F3
625858  AMP_C-Amphetamine   NEGATIVE    EBB74CF9-D12D-4FBC-917F-91D9DAC169F3
625859  BARB-BARBITURATES   7.1 EBB74CF9-D12D-4FBC-917F-91D9DAC169F3
625860  BENZ-BENZODIAZEPINES    1.2 EBB74CF9-D12D-4FBC-917F-91D9DAC169F3
625861  COCN-COCAINE METABOLITES    -105.5  EBB74CF9-D12D-4FBC-917F-91D9DAC169F3
625862  CR-CREATININE (CHEMICAL)    57.8    EBB74CF9-D12D-4FBC-917F-91D9DAC169F3
625863  ETOH-ETHANOL    134.5   EBB74CF9-D12D-4FBC-917F-91D9DAC169F3
625864  METAMP_C-Methamphetamine    NEGATIVE    EBB74CF9-D12D-4FBC-917F-91D9DAC169F3
625865  METD-METHADONE  -32.3   EBB74CF9-D12D-4FBC-917F-91D9DAC169F3
```

thank you for all your help. i think i am getting closer:

```
 select MAX(cast(char_value as decimal(10,2))) from
        (SELECT 
    Char_Number = CASE 
        WHEN id <= 255 THEN RTRIM(id) 
        ELSE '-' END, 
    Char_Value = RTRIM(CASE 
        WHEN id <= 255 THEN CHAR(id) 
        ELSE result END), 
    is_numeric = ISNUMERIC(result), 
    is_really_numeric = dbo.isReallyNumeric(result), 
    is_really_integer = dbo.isReallyInteger(result) 
FROM 
    testresults 
WHERE 
    ISNUMERIC(result) = 1 
    OR dbo.isReallyNumeric(result) = 1 
    OR dbo.isReallyInteger(result) = 1 
 )

    where is_really_numeric=1
```

but i am getting this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
```

Comment: you got typo, that's all

Comment: @KrisIvanov please check my comment to you below

Comment: Try changing from the last parens forward to:    ) A where A.is_really_numeric = 1

Comment: What @SqlACID means is your subselect should have an alias which it doesn't at the moment. On a different note, you should really avoid asking so very different questions in one post. That is not how this site works. It's been designed to be helpful both to those immediately asking questions and to those who are browsing questions in search for an answer. Mixing different questions in one post like that makes things messy and thus not very helpful in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
use SalesDWH
go
SELECT MAX(CAST(Result AS DECIMAL(10,2))) FROM testresults WHERE isnumeric(result)=1
```

But if you get NULL as a result even with this:

```
and dbo.isReallyNumeric([Result]) = 1 
and dbo.isReallyInteger([Result]) = 1
```

then this may be the actual result - there is no any numberic values in the column

**OR**

the really numberic values of column are left- or right-padded with spaces etc...

**OR**

you stripe all the floats with this `dbo.isReallyInteger([Result]) = 1` and you have no pure integers in the table

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Now this depends on your data only - it is runtime error, not parse timedepends, may be you have numbers with more than 10 digits in both integer and decimal parts?

Comment: thank you oleg. i added to my question. please check it once more.

Comment: i just pasted a sample of the data please check i tout

Comment: In sample it is not clear - is there are any whitespace chars, try to produce sample with this: select top 10 cast(Result as varbinary(max)) from testresults

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6119/discussion-between-i-and-oleg-dok)

Comment: i am getting this result 
0x3335372E31 
0x4E45474154495645 
0x372E31 
0x312E32 
0x2D3130352E35 
0x35372E38 
0x3133342E35 
0x4E45474154495645 
0x2D33322E33 
0x4E45474154495645

Answer (score 2):

updated based on guess of what you were looking for

```
SELECT MAX( CAST( [Result] AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) )
FROM [testresults]
WHERE ISNUMERIC( [Result] ) = 1;
```

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: most likely you have some garbage data that is valid `numeric` but will not `cast`, for example symbols like `.`, `-`, `^`, and `+`, you will have to exclude those

Comment: here some ref to get you started http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html

Comment: thanks so much but this looks crazy! i have to do this to know whether it is numeric? there's no easier way out/?

Comment: kris please check again when yo uget an hour

Comment: all you need in your `WHERE` is `dbo.isReallyNumeric([Result]) = 1` get rid of the `OR`s it defeats the purpose of it if you allow the other ones

Answer (score -1):

If you are still getting the error, just give an alias to your inner table.

```
select MAX(cast(char_value as decimal(10,2))) from
        (SELECT 
    Char_Number = CASE 
        WHEN id <= 255 THEN RTRIM(id) 
        ELSE '-' END, 
    Char_Value = RTRIM(CASE 
        WHEN id <= 255 THEN CHAR(id) 
        ELSE result END), 
    is_numeric = ISNUMERIC(result), 
    is_really_numeric = dbo.isReallyNumeric(result), 
    is_really_integer = dbo.isReallyInteger(result) 
FROM 
    testresults 
WHERE 
    ISNUMERIC(result) = 1 
    OR dbo.isReallyNumeric(result) = 1 
    OR dbo.isReallyInteger(result) = 1 
 ) myInnerTable

    where is_really_numeric=1
```